# Transposing large list of address (10000) information in columns and later in csv to upload in mysql

Tags: excel, csv, transpose, libreoffice

I have a list of addresses (about 10000) in either Excel/LibreOffice Calc/Word/LibreOffice Writer. I need to upload them in a Mysql table. The fields and information per company changes ... yet a rough structe would be:

```
Company A 
FirstName LastName Titel
Address
Phone
Email
Website

Company B
FirstName LastName Titel
Address
Phone
Email
Website

Company C
FirstName LastName Titel
Address 
Phone
Email
Website

...
```

Obviously one by one I can Copy- > Past Special -> Transpose them to have the information vertically as a first step.

Goal:

```
Column1|Column2|Column3|Column4|Column5|Column6
Company A | FirstName LastName Titel | Address | Phone | Email | Website
Company B | FirstName LastName Titel | Address | Phone | Email | Website
Company C | FirstName LastName Titel | Address | Phone | Email | Website

...
```

But is there any way to do this automatically and not 10000 times? Not sure if it matters ... I do have a Table of Content ... where the Company Names are Headings ... the rest of the information is Default Style/Text Body

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With data in column **A**, in **B1** enter:

```
=OFFSET($A$1,COLUMNS($A:A)-1+(ROW()-1)*7,0)
```

then copy **B1** to **C1** through **G1**.

Then copy **B1** through **G1** downwards:

[image]

Any single column or row can be mapped into a two dimensional table with a formula.